# Retrieve several values with Flow.Interview

Tags: apex, unit-test, visual-workflow

I'm taking over a project and quite new at developing so I need you're help for this one.
For my tests, I need to create two payments, the actual code allows me to create one payment with a flow, but I don't know how to retrieve an other value from this flow.
I tried to start the flow twice but it raised an exception, I tried a lot of things actually but I can't find the solution... Here is the initial code :

```apex
Order__c currentOrder;
for (Order__c o : escOrders2Upd) {
    System.debug('o.Id : ' + o.Id);
    System.debug('o.Delivery_Date__c : ' + o.Delivery_Date__c);
    System.debug('o.Direct_Invoice__c : ' + o.Direct_Invoice__c);
    if (o.Direct_Invoice__c == false) {
        currentOrder = o;
        break;
    }
}
Map<String, Object> myMap = new Map<String, Object>();
myMap.put('OrderID', currentOrder);
system.debug('create payment:' + myMap);
//prepare payment:
Flow.Interview.Prepare_order_payment_Silent_Mode flowPay = new Flow.Interview.Prepare_order_payment_Silent_Mode(
    myMap
);
flowPay.start();
string paymentId = (String) flowPay.getVariableValue('PaymentID');
string ePaymentId = paymentId;
```

So, I added another entry to `myMap`, because I need another one to create a second payment, but how can I retrieve a second `PaymentID` from that flow?

I tried to create the flow dynamically with a method I found on a forum but I don't know if I'm on the right path (I can't compile, I'm getting an illegal assignment error)

```aped
static Map<String, Object> executeFlow(String flowName, Map<String,Object> variables) {
    Flow.Interview interview;
    String state = '' + variables;

    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        interview = Flow.Interview.createInterview(flowName, variables);
        interview.start();
        state += interview;
    }

    Map<String,Object> result = new Map<String,Object>();
    for (String key : state.split('[^A-Za-z0-9_]+')) {
        Object value = variables.get(key);
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()) value = interview.getVariableValue('PaymentID');
        if (value != null) 
            result.put(key, value);
    }
    return result;
}

Map<String, Object> myMap = new Map<String, Object>();
List<Order__c> currentOrders = new List<Order__c>();
for (Order__c o : escOrders2Upd) {
    if (o.Direct_Invoice__c == false) {
        currentOrders.add(o);
        myMap.put('OrderID', o);
    }
}

String flowName = 'myFlow';
Map<String, Object> flowResult = executeFlow(flowName, myMap);
Set<String> keys = myMap.keySet();
for (String key : keys) {
    Object paymentId = myMap.get(key);
    string ePaymentId = (String) paymentId;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Make the input variable in the flow accept multiple values (a collection), then the `Object` in `Map<String,Object>` is a List<String> of paymentIds

Comment: Thank you @cropredy, I'll try this

Comment: is the Flow supposed to take one OrderId and return _n_ PaymentIds?  It is a little unclear what the Flow's inputs and outputs are.  If your apex needs to launch the flow _x_ times, one per Order in the transaction, then you have to call Flow.Interview _x_ times - there's no apex-driven flow bulkification